# how to call an broadcast receiver from an activity?

Tags: android

I have a broadcast class that blocks the incoming call. I want to call that broadcast receiver from the activity ? Can any one help me fix this. I appreciate your help. 1. Class A extends activity will call Class B that extends BroadcastReceiver, now I want to block calls , only based on certain requirements, which are checked in Class A, if true then call the Class B (or block the call in short)

Answer (score 0):

You can start `BroadcastReceiver`  from Activity as:

```
public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION_NAME = "PACKAGE_NAME.ACTION_NAME";
Intent intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION_NAME);  
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();  
        extras.putString("data", "any_string");  
        intent.putExtras(extras);  
        //send Broadcast from Activity
        sendBroadcast(intent);
```